# Memory leak on non retaining array

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsarray

In a non-ARC project I need to use non retaining arrays. I took the implementation from the old framework Three20. When I track my memory usage with Instruments, it shows me a leak for all my unretained arrays.

Here's the implementation. Do you have an idea ?

```
static const void* RetainNoOp(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value) { return value; }
static void ReleaseNoOp(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value) { }

NSMutableArray* CreateNonRetainingArray() {
    CFArrayCallBacks callbacks = kCFTypeArrayCallBacks;
    callbacks.retain = RetainNoOp;
    callbacks.release = ReleaseNoOp;
    return (NSMutableArray*)CFArrayCreateMutable(nil, 0, &callbacks); // leak here
}
```

Comment: Well did you release the array itself later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `release` on your `CFArray` at some point, otherwise it will leak. According to the ["Create Rule"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029) who calls `CreateNonRetainingArray` is responsible for releasing it.

BTW, it should not be necessary to pass `RetainNoOp` and `ReleaseNoOp`, since CFArray basic behaviour is being [non-retaining/non-releasing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFArrayRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFArrayCallBacks).